# How to plot dictionary of lists efficiently?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having a problem of plotting dictionaries with pandas dataframes. In the code below, I'm running a for loop to iterate over indicies of dictionary. q,fs, and fsd are dictionaries of the same length. The problem is that a file I'm saving is 20 Mb large, and it's definetely too much for a figure with 2 subplots. The question is how can I plot elements of my dictionary of lists and make figures that take less space?

```
fig=plt.figure()
for kk in q:  
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.xlim(min(testset['T(K)']), max(testset['T(K)']))
    plt.plot(q[kk]['T(K)'], fsd[kk](q[kk]['T(K)']), color='green', linewidth=2, label='derivative')
    plt.xlabel('T(K)')      
    plt.title('Data derivative')    
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.xlim(min(testset['T(K)']), max(testset['T(K)']))
    plt.plot(q[kk]['T(K)'], fs[kk](q[kk]['T(K)']), color='blue', linewidth=2, label='fit')    
    plt.scatter(q[kk]['T(K)'],(q[kk]['Vol(V)']), s=3, color='red')  #'r--', lw=2, label='raw data')
    plt.xlabel('T(K)')    
    plt.ylabel('Vol(V)')    
    plt.title('Fit+scattered data')  
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)
plt.show()
```